# Convert string to date in JavaScript to allow comparison

Tags: javascript, date

I have two variables, a date and a time

```
let date = "30.09.2021";
let time = "13:2224.990";
```

how I can convert that to a timestamp so I can compare between the dates?

Comment: Hi ! you may extract the nested values and use the [Date() constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date)

Comment: Did you mean `13:22:24.990` (with two colons)?

Comment: Do you want to combine `date` and `time` to compare to some other (third) date? Or do you want to compare between `date` and `time`? If it's the latter, then there's not enough info for JavaScript to compare between these variables.

Comment: To avoid misunderstandings please explain what  `13:2224.990` means for you.

Comment: It's `hh:mm:ss.SSS`, – hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds

Comment: @DimaParzhitsky,  you are right but it would be better if OP had confirmed it including the second  `:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the timestamp by using the `getTime()` method, but to do so, you firstly need to create a **JavaScript date object** which will allow to use the method.

The problem with your inputs is that their format is not compatible with the `new Date()` method to create the object in the first place, so I use the `slice()` method to change the format of your date and time variables to do all of the above.

```js
// Inputs
let date = "30.09.2021", time = "13:2224.990";

// Changing format
var year = date.slice(6,10),month = date.slice(3,5),day = date.slice(0,2),slice1 = time.slice(0,5),slice2 = time.slice(5,13), newTime = slice1 + ":" + slice2;

// Creating a Date object
const newDate = new Date(year + "-" + month + "-" + day + "T" + newTime); 

// Seconds since 1970/01/01
var seconds = newDate.getTime() / 1000; 

console.log("Timestamp: " + seconds);
```

Comment: In my case the time is has a different format, not 13:22:24, I get an error with your code

Comment: your format is exactly this `"13:2224.990";` ??? it has no errors??

Comment: I changed the code, let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

The [`Date.prototype.toISOString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) method converts date objects to an easy-to-compare format:

```
const date1 = new Date();
const date2 = new Date();

date1.toISOString() < date2.toISOString();
// `true` if `date1` is earlier than `date2`
// `false` if `date1` is later than or equal to `date2`
```